# Power BI - Power Query Case Statement

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, m

Is there a way to do a case statement inside of Power BI, specifically written in `M`?

I have columns that look like this:

```
col_a     col_b      col_c
steve     smith      steve smith
null      james      james
sally     null       sally
```

`Col_c` is a concatenation of columns a and b. If column a or b are null, then I want column c to be null, no matter what.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M has a fairly standard `if`, `then`, `else` syntax.

```
if [col_a] = null or [col_b] = null
then null
else [col_a] & " " & [col_b]
```